# Can I trust a random internet user?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, internet, edim-witnesses, trust-neemanut

Does the halacha of עד אחד נאמן באיסורין (a single witness is trusted in matters of prohibition) apply to a random internet users?  If someone presents themselves as being a practicing Jew, can I take their word for it on information they give me?

For example, if someone says "I called the OU and they said that all cheese sold on Tuesdays is aged," can I believe him or her that the OU said such?

Does it make any difference if this anonymous internet user has a [solid reputation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) of some kind or another?

I do *not* mean to ask if I can accept his or her halachic opinions - for that you should [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: Is this something which you could check but don't want to or something you can't check? (eg. the OU's official position is X vs I was present in the factory that day and they used the blue box of flour)

Comment: @DoubleAA An answer could explain as much if there is a difference between the two. (i.e. I'm asking about both, or all, cases of reporting facts)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, you only have about 19000 reputation. You are probably a goy.

Comment: Nice question. +1. Even more complicated is when someone like me quotes a certain Rabbi's ruling. Its very possible that that very same Rabbi would rule differently for you! This is a side complication not reserved for random internet users but something people should consider nonetheless.

Comment: .... He asked a bunch of random internet users.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Rov people on Earth, even not online, are Goyim.  We have chazakos for these things.  See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/46181/4794) for more on that.

Comment: @YEZ but here most people don't even claim to be Jewish

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It's certainly implied by many of them.  And you don't _have_ to say the magic formula "I am Jewish" - actions and circumstantial evidence can count.

Comment: Why should we be able to answer this question? After all, we're random Internet users.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the wikipedia standard of [verifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Verifiability) and I try to apply it to myself and others on the internet. If someone just states a fact as true, I usually find it suspect. If something is true, it should be possible to provide a verifiable source. Verifiable means that "I heard from a friend" doesn't work because the reader can't verify it. However citing a book, webpage, or organization you can call to check out the statements is verifiable. Even if you don't do the verification yourself, verifiable statements that are false are more likely to be uncovered by someone else, and the people making those statements will lose reputation (or someone will just post the contradictory discovery).

Comment: But can you provide a verifiable source that this standard is halachically valid?

Comment: @DoubleAA Shulchan aruch siman 903.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Those can happen even in  printed, linked-to sources

Comment: Your source should be [edit]ed into your answer. And siman 903?

Comment: @YeZ, I suspect that it's in the "fifth *cheilek*."